# JWT being successfully validated across different successfully logged in users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have created a gateway api for validating users through jwt by following :

https://medium.com/@arjunac009/spring-boot-microservice-with-centralized-authentication-zuul-eureka-jwt-5719e05fde29

Everything is working fine but i got into an issue. I am using Restlet and Postman to test. I logged in with 2 different users using these 2 test tools and got 2 different JWTs. However, these JWTs are being successfully validated across different users. Means, if i pass JWT of 1st user for doing secure operations with 2nd user, validation is successful. I do not think it is a desirable behavior. Because if someone hacks one user's jwt he can perform operations under 2nd user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any kind of token based authentication also has this kind of man-in-the-middle attack problem which the JWT can be stolen by the attacker by eavesdropping your network traffic. That 's why we need to use `SSL` to encrypt the network traffic if we want to prevent the network traffic from being eavesdropped.

On the other hand , you can introduce the expiry time on JWT such that in case of the JWT is stolen by others , it can only be used for a short period of time.

Comment: Thanks Chan for your reply.

Comment: What is the appropriate time which one should set for expiry?